# associating a request with response

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, httprequest, httpresponse

I have an app in which I want to make several asynchronous requests and then once I receive the response refresh the view or something like that.
How can I determine that a response is associated with a particular request?
Since this is asynchronous, I don't want to maintain property for the URL, as several requests would be made.

```
    [HttpRequestManager makeASynchronousRequest:url withTarget:self withSelector:@selector(receivedImageData:)];

    - (void) receivedImageData:(NSMutableData *) data
    {
        if (data) {
            UIImage *image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

            NSString *path = [self savePngImage:image withLocalURL:**URL should be the one I created earlier**];
            if (path) {
                [self.delegate receivedImage:image];
            }
            else
           {
           }
        }
    }
```

Can I pass the URL in the @selector(receivedImageData:)?

Comment: Usually the 'sender' is passed in as a parameter - are you sure it's just the data that's coming back?

Comment: Yup.. its just the data that is coming back